# Delete mounting points

Tags: mountpoint

I primarily using Ubuntu (16.04) but have also Win10 installed. Recently I need Windows more often and switch between the two OS. I have two partitions with the operating systems (C for Win and 'Computer' for Ubuntu) and a third 'DATA' which is shared between the two OS. Usually 'DATA' is mounted in

```
/media/me/DATA
```

Since the last update in Win10 the mounting point $media/me/DATA$ is inaccessible. The partition DATA is now mounted in

```
/media/me/DATA1
```

Therefore all my projects linked in software and libraries now all have broken links (since they point to /media/me/DATA)

My question: Is it save to delete the 'broken' mounting point? My fear is that I damage the files on the original partition.

Comment: You haven't said how you mounted your partition; if it was via `/etc/fstab` or the file system table mount point should not have changed, so providing your mounting method may provide clues to your issue & subsequently advice given.

Comment: I linked the partition on my launcher, when I click on it is mounted. I do not know how this is done